# Get the currently executing method name of current thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, clr

I am using a background worker to process big files in a loop lasting for hours. In the GUI, I show the currently progressed file with a label, and a progressbar control. Everything is most of the time ok.

My problem is; sometimes, (maybe some locked or corrupt files, Although I handled everthing in try catches), after some hours, current file name and also progressbar value doesn't change on GUI (for ex. at the 10000 th. file), although GUI is still responsive to me...That is, it is not an GUI freeze issue. But it also doesn't say that background worker finished (I handled both reportprogress and completed events correctly)..And unfortunately, it keeps at that state, so I kill and restart program, but again it stucks at same file.

So; I want to understand WHERE (at which method, or line) the code got stuck...Try catch blocks doesnt give me any clue..

To achieve this, I am planning to put a button on GUI, and when it got stuck on some file, I will press that button and it'll give me a DEBUG information, containing currently executing (stucked namely) method name and line number if possible...

StackTrace etc. is not a solution, since when I use it, it gives me the trace of the method I wrote it in...

Any idea?

(Solutions such as, continuing with the next line of code also suffices for me, I dont want to restart my program and lose so much time again)

Comment: have you tried logging? ie to a database or to a file?

Comment: You will need to debug your program.  So use a debugger.

Comment: I think, it seems logging is the best way...

Answer (score 0):

You could try a new component developed by the Microsoft CLR team: ClrMD: [.NET Crash Dump and Live Process Inspection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx)

> ClrMD is a set of advanced APIs for programmatically inspecting a
>   crash dump of a .NET program much in the same way as the SOS Debugging
>   Extensions (SOS). It allows you to write automated crash analysis for
>   your applications and automate many common debugger tasks.